# Angular templates return 404 when JS is minified

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, templates

We are using Angular with ASP.NET MVC.

We are also using ui-bootstrap (or AngularUI).

The pattern for controls with ui-bootstrap is that all of the html templates are set using `$templateCache.put()`, including the one custom template that I added.

All of our scripts are being bundled using ASP.NET's BundleCollection. For release builds, the JS files are minified as well.

Here is the problem: Everything works great without minification. When the JS is minified for the release build, however, the browser is getting a 404 error after trying to download the template files ("template/control/control.html") from the server. These files aren't on the server but are supposed to be simply picked up from the template cache.

Any suggestions? I can provide more detail, but I'm not sure what details are important yet.

**Details**

Most of the templates (including one template that is failing to resolve) are inside of the ui-bootstrap-tmpls file from ui-bootstrap.

I did create one custom template. This template is in a file called "customAngularBootstrapTemplates.js". First, here are some snapshots of my BundleCollection configuration:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/clientside_frameworks").Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"
            // Plus other frameworks (lodash, etc)
        ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", bootstrapJS_CdnPath).Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-ui", ui_bootstrap_CdnPath).Include(
            "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap*"));

// ... A few other references

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myAngularJS").Include(
            "~/Scripts/MyAngular/MyModule.js",
            "~/Scripts/MyAngular/*.js")); // Matches the custom template file
```

Here's my template file, for the record:

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/datepicker.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/datepicker.html",
      "<table>\n" +
      "  <thead>\n" +
      "    <tr>\n" +
      "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\"></i></button></th>\n" +
      "      <th colspan=\"{{rows[0].length - 2 + showWeekNumbers}}\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>\n" +
      "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\"></i></button></th>\n" +
      "    </tr>\n" +
      "    <tr ng-show=\"labels.length > 0\" class=\"h6\">\n" +
      "      <th ng-show=\"showWeekNumbers\" class=\"text-center\">#</th>\n" +
      "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in labels\" class=\"text-center\">{{label}}</th>\n" +
      "    </tr>\n" +
      "  </thead>\n" +
      "  <tbody>\n" +
      "    <tr ng-repeat=\"row in rows\">\n" +
      "      <td ng-show=\"showWeekNumbers\" class=\"text-center\"><em>{{ getWeekNumber(row) }}</em></td>\n" +
      "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row\" class=\"text-center\">\n" +
      "        <button type=\"button\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-class=\"{'btn-info': dt.selected}\" ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\" ng-disabled=\"dt.disabled\"><span ng-class=\"{'text-muted': dt.secondary}\">{{dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
      "      </td>\n" +
      "    </tr>\n" +
      "  </tbody>\n" +
      "</table>\n" +
      "");
}]);
```

Console errors from Chrome:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://www.mydomain.com/url/template/datepicker/datepicker.html"

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://www.mydomain.com/url/template/datepicker/popup.html"

"Error: [$compile:tpload]   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Fdatepicker%2Fdatepicker.html
   at Error (native)
   at http://www.mydomain.com/bundles/clientside_frameworks?v-ugF3A5jxJI7816t_MmfA0Oju5BGizHxJtDkkK1q72HI1:1:447
...
..."

... one more compile error.

Comment: I would suggest providing the past of the code that adds the template to the cache.

Comment: Could you provide the errors from your console? I've had issues with the BundleTransformer nuGet package with Angular (minification re-naming $scope, $http, etc) but it looks like that may not be the issue in your case (with how your code is written).

Comment: Hm...do you declare the module as a dependency for your main modula/app ?

Comment: Like so: `var myModule = angular.module("myModule", ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

Answer (score 1):

After much pain, it appears that I have found a solution.

Putting this in the bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-ui", ui_bootstrap_CdnPath).Include(
            "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap*"));
```

Is not good enough. The cdn path only resolves the JS, but not the UIBootstrap template file.

Everything seems to be working once I changed this to:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-ui", ui_bootstrap_CdnPath).Include(
            "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-0.10.0.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-ui-templates", ui_bootstrap_templates_CdnPath).Include(
            "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"));
```